# Static QT unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to build using static qt for a while but i can't get rid of these errors .

```
      <QtGuiApplication4> (29 items)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_New_Face referenced in function "public: static class QStringList __cdecl QBasicFontDatabase::addTTFile(class QByteArray const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?addTTFile@QBasicFontDatabase@@SA?AVQStringList@@ABVQByteArray@@0@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Get_PS_Font_Info referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QFontEngineFT::init(struct QFontEngine::FaceId,bool,enum QFontEngine::GlyphFormat,class QFreetypeFace *)" (?init@QFontEngineFT@@QAE_NUFaceId@QFontEngine@@_NW4GlyphFormat@3@PAVQFreetypeFace@@@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Load_Sfnt_Table referenced in function "bool __cdecl ft_getSfntTable(void *,unsigned int,unsigned char *,unsigned int *)" (?ft_getSfntTable@@YA_NPAXIPAEPAI@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_GlyphSlot_Oblique referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QFontEngineFT::addGlyphsToPath(unsigned int *,struct QFixedPoint *,int,class QPainterPath *,class QFlags<enum QTextItem::RenderFlag>)" (?addGlyphsToPath@QFontEngineFT@@UAEXPAIPAUQFixedPoint@@HPAVQPainterPath@@V?$QFlags@W4RenderFlag@QTextItem@@@@@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_GlyphSlot_Embolden referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QFontEngineFT::addGlyphsToPath(unsigned int *,struct QFixedPoint *,int,class QPainterPath *,class QFlags<enum QTextItem::RenderFlag>)" (?addGlyphsToPath@QFontEngineFT@@UAEXPAIPAUQFixedPoint@@HPAVQPainterPath@@V?$QFlags@W4RenderFlag@QTextItem@@@@@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Outline_Get_Bitmap referenced in function "public: struct QFontEngineFT::Glyph * __thiscall QFontEngineFT::loadGlyph(struct QFontEngineFT::QGlyphSet *,unsigned int,struct QFixed,enum QFontEngine::GlyphFormat,bool)const " (?loadGlyph@QFontEngineFT@@QBEPAUGlyph@1@PAUQGlyphSet@1@IUQFixed@@W4GlyphFormat@QFontEngine@@_N@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Outline_Transform referenced in function "public: struct QFontEngineFT::Glyph * __thiscall QFontEngineFT::loadGlyph(struct QFontEngineFT::QGlyphSet *,unsigned int,struct QFixed,enum QFontEngine::GlyphFormat,bool)const " (?loadGlyph@QFontEngineFT@@QBEPAUGlyph@1@PAUQGlyphSet@1@IUQFixed@@W4GlyphFormat@QFontEngine@@_N@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Outline_Translate referenced in function "public: struct QFontEngineFT::Glyph * __thiscall QFontEngineFT::loadGlyph(struct QFontEngineFT::QGlyphSet *,unsigned int,struct QFixed,enum QFontEngine::GlyphFormat,bool)const " (?loadGlyph@QFontEngineFT@@QBEPAUGlyph@1@PAUQGlyphSet@1@IUQFixed@@W4GlyphFormat@QFontEngine@@_N@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Vector_Transform referenced in function "public: struct QFontEngineFT::Glyph * __thiscall QFontEngineFT::loadGlyph(struct QFontEngineFT::QGlyphSet *,unsigned int,struct QFixed,enum QFontEngine::GlyphFormat,bool)const " (?loadGlyph@QFontEngineFT@@QBEPAUGlyph@1@PAUQGlyphSet@1@IUQFixed@@W4GlyphFormat@QFontEngine@@_N@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_MulFix referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QFontEngineFT::init(struct QFontEngine::FaceId,bool,enum QFontEngine::GlyphFormat,class QFreetypeFace *)" (?init@QFontEngineFT@@QAE_NUFaceId@QFontEngine@@_NW4GlyphFormat@3@PAVQFreetypeFace@@@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_MulDiv referenced in function "void __cdecl scaleOutline(struct FT_FaceRec_ *,struct FT_GlyphSlotRec_ *,long,long)" (?scaleOutline@@YAXPAUFT_FaceRec_@@PAUFT_GlyphSlotRec_@@JJ@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Get_Char_Index referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall QFontEngineFT::glyphIndex(unsigned int)const " (?glyphIndex@QFontEngineFT@@UBEII@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Set_Charmap referenced in function "public: static class QFreetypeFace * __cdecl QFreetypeFace::getFace(struct QFontEngine::FaceId const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?getFace@QFreetypeFace@@SAPAV1@ABUFaceId@QFontEngine@@ABVQByteArray@@@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Matrix_Multiply referenced in function "public: struct QFontEngineFT::Glyph * __thiscall QFontEngineFT::loadGlyph(struct QFontEngineFT::QGlyphSet *,unsigned int,struct QFixed,enum QFontEngine::GlyphFormat,bool)const " (?loadGlyph@QFontEngineFT@@QBEPAUGlyph@1@PAUQGlyphSet@1@IUQFixed@@W4GlyphFormat@QFontEngine@@_N@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Get_Postscript_Name referenced in function "public: struct QFontEngine::Properties __thiscall QFreetypeFace::properties(void)const " (?properties@QFreetypeFace@@QBE?AUProperties@QFontEngine@@XZ)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Load_Glyph referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QFontEngineFT::addGlyphsToPath(unsigned int *,struct QFixedPoint *,int,class QPainterPath *,class QFlags<enum QTextItem::RenderFlag>)" (?addGlyphsToPath@QFontEngineFT@@UAEXPAIPAUQFixedPoint@@HPAVQPainterPath@@V?$QFlags@W4RenderFlag@QTextItem@@@@@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Set_Char_Size referenced in function "public: static class QFreetypeFace * __cdecl QFreetypeFace::getFace(struct QFontEngine::FaceId const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?getFace@QFreetypeFace@@SAPAV1@ABUFaceId@QFontEngine@@ABVQByteArray@@@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Select_Size referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QFreetypeFace::computeSize(struct QFontDef const &,int *,int *,bool *)" (?computeSize@QFreetypeFace@@QAEXABUQFontDef@@PAH1PA_N@Z)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Done_FreeType referenced in function "public: __thiscall QtFreetypeData::~QtFreetypeData(void)" (??1QtFreetypeData@@QAE@XZ)
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Init_FreeType referenced in function "public: static class QFreetypeFace * __cdecl QFreetypeFace::getFace(struct QFontEngine::FaceId const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?getFace@QFreetypeFace@@SAPAV1@ABUFaceId@QFontEngine@@ABVQByteArray@@@Z)
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FT_Get_Sfnt_Table
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Get_Sfnt_Table referenced in function "public: static class QStringList __cdecl QBasicFontDatabase::addTTFile(class QByteArray const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?addTTFile@QBasicFontDatabase@@SA?AVQStringList@@ABVQByteArray@@0@Z)
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FT_Done_Face
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Done_Face referenced in function "public: static class QStringList __cdecl QBasicFontDatabase::addTTFile(class QByteArray const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?addTTFile@QBasicFontDatabase@@SA?AVQStringList@@ABVQByteArray@@0@Z)
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FT_New_Memory_Face
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_New_Memory_Face referenced in function "public: static class QStringList __cdecl QBasicFontDatabase::addTTFile(class QByteArray const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?addTTFile@QBasicFontDatabase@@SA?AVQStringList@@ABVQByteArray@@0@Z)
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FT_New_Face
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Set_Transform referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QFontEngineFT::getUnscaledGlyph(unsigned int,class QPainterPath *,struct glyph_metrics_t *)" (?getUnscaledGlyph@QFontEngineFT@@UAEXIPAVQPainterPath@@PAUglyph_metrics_t@@@Z)
Error LNK1120: 24 unresolved externals
```

I am using these libraries :

```
ws2_32.lib
imm32.lib
winmm.lib
qtharfbuzzng.lib
qtpcre.lib
Qt5PlatformSupport.lib
qwindows.lib
opengl32.lib
```

Can any of you explain me what i am doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Aren't there a lot more .lib files from Qt that you need to link with?

Comment: from the tutorials i followed this should be enough

Comment: ***from the tutorials i followed this should be enough***  I say that is not enough.

Comment: well can you give me 1 hint please ?

Comment: There should be over 100 libs in your qtbase\lib folder. Although obviously not all are needed.

Comment: "What I am doing wrong" - not googling `_FT_New_Face`, or any of the other symbols. The first hit on google has your answer. You don't even need to click on the search result, just read the result's **header**. I'll let you do it since you need to get in the habit of doing it. Really.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the exact same issue. You're missing the freetype library `qtfreetype.lib`.
Add the following line to your .pro file

```
LIBS += -lqtfreetype
```

Answer (score 0):

You need QtCore and QtGui at a minimum for this. QString is in QtCore and QGuiApplication is in QtGui. If your Qt usage is restricted to user interface activities, that might be enough. Otherwise, for each class that's failing to link, look in Qt Assistant. The "qmake" note at the top of the page says which library contains that class.

For instance, for Qstring, it has "qmake: QT += core". For Visual Studio on Windows, the actual filenames for the "core" library are Qt5Core.dll (release) Qt5Cored.dll (debug).

Answer (score 0):

Added my case, hope this will helpful.

1. I'm lost one CPP file in the library project
2. Be careful when compilation (Lib & Project) has different option MT/MD options